# talend 8- tLogRow returns empty values when in the previous steps the variable are with values

Tags: logging, talend

As you can see in the pictures below all the variables in the previous steps have its values. I printed them using java code. type of row6 =is Struct.
In the next step I am using tLogRows to print them again, but all the values appear empty. I am not sure why this is happening, any help will be apricated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to use a tjavarow or a tJavaflex , it's not very appropriate to use a tjava here to pass the flow ;)

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa  do you mean instead of tjava I use tjavarow or a tJavaflex  ? Ok , I will try. what's the relation of it with tLogRow? do you know why I am getting empty string in each value?

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa Another reason of using tJava is that we are overwritting on our context as context.source_file_dir  and with using only tjavarow we will loose this as it's assigning to output_row.source_file_dir and not context.source_file_dir

Comment: tjavaflex and tjavarow would do the same , delete the tjava and try those component